# How to click through canvas tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently working on a chess program in python (Tkinter), I have got a board to generate with buttons so that I can click on pieces, I planned to use a canvas for each of the chess pieces and then move them around. Is there any way to make it so I can click through the canvas?

```
try:
    from Tkinter import *
except:
    from tkinter import *

class grid_piece():

    def __init__(self, canvas, row, column, colour_boolean, size):
        colour_1 = '#934904'
        colour_2 = '#fce2c9'
        self.row = row
        self.column = column
        grid_piece = Button(canvas, height = size // 100,
                            width = size // 50,
                            command=lambda: my_board.button_press([row, column]))
        grid_piece.grid(row=row, column = column)
        if colour_boolean:
            grid_piece.configure(bg = colour_1, fg = colour_1)
        else:
            grid_piece.configure(bg = colour_2, fg = colour_2)

class pawn():

    def __init__(self, size, canvas, position):
        self.pawn_canvas = Canvas(canvas, width = size // 8, height = size // 8
                                  )
        self.pawn_canvas.grid(row = position[0], column = position[1])

class Board():

    def __init__(self, master, size):
        self.canvas = Canvas(master, width=size, height=size)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.size = size

    def generate_board(self):
        colour_boolean = True
        self.board_array = []
        for column in range(8):
            column_pieces = []
            colour_boolean = not colour_boolean
            for row in range(8):
                colour_boolean = not colour_boolean
                piece = grid_piece(self.canvas, row, column, colour_boolean, self.size)
                column_pieces.append(piece)
            self.board_array.append(column_pieces)

    def display_pieces(self):
        white_pieces = []
        black_pieces = []       

        for x in range(8):
            Pawn = pawn(self.size, self.canvas, [1, x])
            white_pieces.append(Pawn)

    def button_press(self, position):
        print(position)

def onclick(*args):
    print(*args)       

root = Tk()

my_board = Board(root, 600)
my_board.generate_board()
my_board.display_pieces()

root.mainloop()
```

Here is an image of my board, the white squares are blank canvases that I will turn into objects once I create the pieces.

[image]

Comment: Why use buttons behind a canvas? Just bind click to canvas objects.

Comment: The easiest way to move the pieces is probably for the first click on a button to specify the source and the second click to specify the destination. The game rules can then determine whether that is a valid move for the piece and update the button to show the correct piece.

Comment: If you are using the buttons already, I'd just use a button image to show what type of piece is at each square.

Comment: You can also create buttons on the canvas directly. There are a couple of ways you can approach something like this. You can either use buttons and dynamically assign the image of each piece to each button or you can create image objects/button objects directly to the canvas. In each case you will likely need to dynamically assign images.

Comment: "I planned to use a canvas for each of the chess pieces" Looks like a terrible idea.

Comment: *"so I can click through the canvas?"*: Read [Coordinate Systems](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#coordinate-systems)